# Solr autocomplete that does spellchecking along with bringing category in which it exists

Tags: solr

I got the spell checker working and I need to use the results in an other query so that I can produce something like this (searched term plus category):

[image]

can you please direct me on how can I achieve this.

Comment: These are usually generated by creating a facet on the category field - what have you tried?

Comment: I understand you can you use facet or group (better option because it can be sorted by score rather than count). My question is is there a way to use the outcome of the spellchecker into the query that does the searching without the need to query twice.

Comment: Usually you should try to avoid being smart about spellchecks, as there will be situations where the spellcheck isn't what the user want - if they're searching for a lesser known item (for example, there are plenty of products named pixl or pxe) it'll be impossible for them to actually perform the search. If anything, you should combine both queries and present both options.

Comment: You are probably right. I should present spellcheck as an option to the user just like "Google's did you mean" and not force it. Thank you for your feedback.